# How to export sql data from one server to another server using script/code?

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2012, transfer

I have a Live database on Server1 on which data is feeded frequently (daily). I need to access this on different server (Server2) which needs to be updated every week with the data from Server1. How do we do this?

I have no idea of how to begin. A bit of investigation helped me know about Sql Job Agents, but I need to do this using code (preferably C#) , so that data updation occurs automatically on the destination server.
Can someone please tell me other ways to do this?

Currently I have to manually take backup from server1 and restore it on server2. How can we automate this?

Comment: One word: **Replication**. Forget custom solutions unless you have special cases which can't be realized using replication. The only limit is if you're talking about Express edition of SQL Server. Replication is available with Standard edition or better. Start [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198(v=sql.110).aspx)

Comment: I wish I could upvote @LightBulb more than once. Do. Not. Reinvent. Replication. You **are** going to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: Why do you think you need C# to export the data automatically? You *can* schedule any job. Even the backup/restore procedure can be written as a scheduled job.

Comment: @CodeCaster replication may be too much or too complex for a simple data copying scenario. It *does* require configuration. It's not a magic bullet. The OP should consider what he wants to do and *read* about replication, jobs, scheduling etc. Snapshot replication or not? How big is the data?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos of course it requires OP to educate themself about replication. Of course OP could opt to ignore all existing solutions and decide to code something up themselves, but that won't magically make the problem go away. Data replication is not trivial, and I've seen it done poorly way more often than correctly. Given OP's _"I have no idea of how to begin"_, I do recommend SQL Server Replication, which you can learn about and set up in mere hours. If **all** OP wants to do is to automate taking a backup on server 1 and restoring it on server 2, well ... then they should search.

Comment: And SQL Server's Books Online has entire sections that explain all this, even going step by step. A few hours of reading and a bit of experimentation can save weeks trying to recover from problems in production

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I went through some of the tutorials and now am able to replicate the data on both server. I am working on how to schedule the replication process. I have just started working on these things, so it will take a while.